# Error while uploading an image on Jupyter notebook using cv2.imread() function

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I am totally new to programming and just started learning Python 15 days back.
I am trying to upload an image on Jupyter notebook using the `imread()` function but am not able to upload an image.
Any file path I specify, whether from my computer or online link, I am not able to upload an image.
It does not throw any error, but in next step when I enquire the datatype of image - it shows `Nonetype` i.e no image uploaded.

Note:- I am using the Jupyter cloud - which means I directly logon to Jupyter website and am using it through a web browser.

I have uploaded a screenshot of my Jupyter notebook program.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Ozw.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-3oioonok/view/binder/python--study.jpg')

type(img)
```

Comment: Seems weird. Try to check whether you have installed `opencv-python` to the proper env. Execute `! pip3 list` in a new cell after the installation and look for `opencv-python`. Also, try to open local image. Before reading an image, check if it exists with `os.path.exists(file_path)`

Answer (score 0):

The path you specify should be a file system path instead of a URL. Since your notebook is in the cloud, using paths to your computer wouldn't work either. If `python--study.jpg` is in the same directory as your notebook on this cloud server, you could do:

```
img=cv2.imread('python--study.jpg')
```